# liftweb notice/message/warning does not work for the second time

Tags: jquery, scala, lift

I am trying to display validation messages in an app built using `liftweb 2.4` scala web framework.
The app has only one text box and submit button to add the text to db.
On submit the snippet code checks whether the text box is empty and displays a message.

```
 package snippet {

object Notes {

  def noteForm(in: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
    def add() = {
      if (note.description.isEmpty()) {
        S.error("descError", "Please enter a note")
      } else {
        note.save
        NotesServer ! "refresh"
        S.notice("descMessage", "Note added.")
      }

    }
    bind("f", in,
      "desc" -%> SHtml.text(note.description.is, note.description(_)),
      "submit" -%> SHtml.submit("Note It !", add)) ++ SHtml.hidden(add _)
  }

  def delete(note: Note): JsCmd = {
    note.delete_!
    NotesServer ! "refresh"
    S.notice("descMessage", "Note deleted.")
  }

}

object note extends RequestVar[Note]({ Note.create })

}
```

the html is

```
 <lift:surround with="default" at="content">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span11">
        <form class="lift:form.ajax">
            <lift:Notes.noteForm>
                <f:desc id="desc" placeholder="what do you want to note?"
                    class="xxlarge" />
                <f:submit class="btn primary" />
            </lift:Notes.noteForm>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span11">
        <lift:msg id="descError" errorClass="alert-message error" />
        <lift:msg id="descMessage" noticeClass="alert-message success" />
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="lift:comet?type=NotesComet" id="notes">
        <div class="row show-grid">
            <div class="note span10 lpad20">
                <div style="display: inline" class="desclist"></div>
                <a class="close rpad10 tpad10" href="javascript://">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

code for comet

```
object NotesServer extends LiftActor with ListenerManager {

def createUpdate =  Note.allNotes


override def lowPriority = _ match{
  case "refresh" => updateListeners()
}

}  
class NotesComet extends CometActor with CometListener {
 private var notes: List[Note] = List()

 def registerWith = NotesServer

 override def lowPriority = {
  case n: List[Note] => notes = n; reRender()
 }

def render = "#notes" #> {
  (notes.reverse.map(note => ".desclist *" #> note.description &
  ".close [onclick]" #> ajaxInvoke(() => Notes.delete(note))))
}

}
```

**The message display works only for the first time perfectly with fade-in and fade-out, but fails subsequently.**

here is what i have in `Boot.scala` for fade in and fade out

```
LiftRules.noticesEffects.default.set((notice: Box[NoticeType.Value], id: String) => {
  Full(JqJsCmds.FadeOut(id, 2 seconds, 2 seconds))
})
```

the following lift tag

```
<lift:msg id="descError" errorClass="alert-message error" />
```

produces

```
<span id="descError" ></span>
```

and after submit, the above html changes to the following. fade-in and fade-out works perfectly

```
<span id="descError" style="display: none;">
<span id="descError">
    <span class="alert-message error">Please enter a note</span>
</span>
</span>
```

for the subsequent submit events the message is not shown because there are two span tags with same id `descError`

the problem is clear now, but not sure how to fix this.

**update**

i tried the same code with liftweb 2.5-M3 and the difference i noticed is that the generated html after submit is as following.

```
<span id="descError" style="display: none;">
    <span class="alert-message error">Please enter a note</span>
</span>
```

but still the message is not displayed for the subsequent submits.

Comment: You need to give us more information about what you're doing.  Regular or Ajax forms?  Does it work without the fade?  What do you mean by "first time"?  Is it that the message appears when a form is submitted once, but does not appear on subsequent submits?  If so, what happens after the second submit?  Is the message cleared?  It would also help if you posted more of the code that handles the form submission.

Comment: hi Dave, i have improvised the question little more with code snippets.

Comment: Ok, that's much better.  While it may not be relevant to this issue, the first thing I want to point out is that the bind() method of templating is effectively deprecated.  You should really update your project to use Css Selectors throughout.  That out of the way, I'm still a bit confused about what you're looking to accomplish here.  On your first submit, if a not doesn't exist, the message is displayed, correct?  Is the issue that on the second submit the message is/is not cleared?  Or that you expect it to display a second time?

Comment: yes, on first submit the message is displayed, but for the second submit it is not displayed.

Comment: I think this is the type of issue that is going to need a reproducible example to track down.  You're probably better off posting to the Lift list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb, and if you create your test case and post it to github beforehand https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Posting_example_code you'll get your question answered faster.